# Does anyone know if Kendo UI Bootstrap theme is version 3 or 4?

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I know Bootstrap 4 is still alpha, but I'm curious if I should use a site template based on 3 to integrate with the Kendo UI for Angular library.

Comment: Just reading over the documents, it appears that you can use either

Comment: The theme is build on top of Bootstrap 4. That being said, it will be better to use 4+ only.